# Find By ID and Remove From MongoDB array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**My Collection:**

```
  geoGraphicalFilter: {
    aCountries: [String],
    aCities: [String],
    aCoordinates: [{
      coordinates: { type: Array }
    }]
  }
```

**CollectionData**

```
"geoGraphicalFilter": {
            "aCoordinates": [
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("5acb641d93fa0e52557fc6aa"),
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            72.42919972527011,
                            23.0437703991947
                        ],
                        [
                            72.45031407464302,
                            23.045823913521474
                        ],
                        [
                            72.43263295281557,
                            23.030500782775746
                        ],
                        [
                            72.42919972527011,
                            23.0437703991947
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("5acb641d93fa0e52557fc6ac"),
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            72.51520207511979,
                            23.038241551175616
                        ],
                        [
                            72.55399754632015,
                            23.03934733892872
                        ],
                        [
                            72.51812031852671,
                            23.025129376064214
                        ],
                        [
                            72.51520207511979,
                            23.038241551175616
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": ObjectId("5acb641d93fa0e52557fc6ad"),
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            72.44653752434493,
                            23.02828905299478
                        ],
                        [
                            72.4896245299627,
                            23.02828905299478
                        ],
                        [
                            72.45477727044641,
                            23.0194417709901
                        ],
                        [
                            72.44653752434493,
                            23.02828905299478


            ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("5acb641d93fa0e52557fc6ab"),
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        72.47451832878957,
                        23.045350028380867
                    ],
                    [
                        72.50576069939376,
                        23.04835127278581
                    ],
                    [
                        72.47949650871226,
                        23.031606634051897
                    ],
                    [
                        72.47451832878957,
                        23.045350028380867
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ],
        "aCities": [],
        "aCountries": []
    }
```

**Remove From Database Snippet**

```
const deleteZones = (req,res,next) => {
  var body = _.pick(req.body, ["zones"]);
  var zoneList = body.zones;
  debug(zoneList)
  var promise = function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      zoneList.forEach(itemA => {
        console.log(itemA.coordinates)
        huntingModel.update(
          { _id: req.body.id },
          { $pull: { 'geoGraphicalFilter.aCoordinates':  itemA.id} },
          (error, success) => {
            if (error) console.log(error);
            console.log(success);
          }
        );
      });
      resolve();
    });
  };
  promise().then(function() {
    return res.status(200).jsonp({
      message: adminMessages.succ_zone_removed
    });
  });
}
```

Now the scenario is like when I am trying to delete data it shows success message but data does not get deleted.

```
  var object = {
    id:this.id,
    zones: this.zonesDelete // Contains list of id
  };
```

I am getting `object` in a requested body and I want to find the document from a collection and delete the particular array element by finding an id in `geoGraphicalFilter.aCoordinates` and wants to remove it.

Comment: you want to remove an element from the array right ? in simple words ?

Comment: Yes I want to remove Whole element from array

Comment: whole element mean ? 1- `[
                            72.51520207511979,
                            23.038241551175616
                        ]` or just `72.51520207511979`

Comment: `{ "_id": ObjectId("5acb641d93fa0e52557fc6ab"),
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        72.47451832878957,
                        23.045350028380867
                    ],[
                        72.50576069939376,
                        23.04835127278581
                    ],[
                        72.47949650871226,
                        23.031606634051897
                    ],[
                        72.47451832878957,
                        23.045350028380867
                    ] ] }` Whole elemnet associated with `ID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation of [$pull operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) you can either specify a value or a condition

i.e.

```
{ $pull: { <field1>: <value|condition>, <field2>: <value|condition>, ... } }
```

In your scenario you need to either specify complete value of one or more **aCoordinates** item object or an condition that matches one or more **aCoordinates** item

Add the condition where you match id of aCoordinates item i.e.

Use following pull condition to solve the issue:

```
        huntingModel.update(
          { _id: req.body.id },
          { $pull: { 'geoGraphicalFilter.aCoordinates':  {'_id' : ObjectId(itemA.id)}} },
          (error, success) => {
            if (error) console.log(error);
            console.log(success);
          }
       );
```

Comment: it is working with foreach loop but now I want to give array element of id to delete the Array from a collection. What I meant is it will take a lot of queries to delete one-one arrays, I want to archive in only one Query

Comment: Use can use $in clause to specify multiple _ids